# What is the best way to store a hexadecimal value in an array in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, arrays, hash, keccak

I am attempting to store a hash (web3.sha3) into an array in a smart contract.

What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is a little unclear, but are you asking the datatype to store it in? Do you want to store the individual bytes of the hash into different slots in an array? If so, use the `bytes` datatype. If you want to store an array of sha3 hashes, you should use a `bytes32[]` array and store the hashes at different indexes in the array.

If you need more information, consider editing your question to add specific needs you have.